# Error: unexpected symbol in "dat <- read.csv(file=result of"

Tags: r

I am new to `R`. I am trying to enter bellow command in `R` console

```
dat <- read.csv(file=result of file.choose(),header=T)
```

Why am I getting following error ?

```
Error: unexpected symbol in "dat <- read.csv(file=result of"
```

Comment: remove "result of"?

Comment: think what you are sending to `file`. You are sending a string with spaces in it. Surely that is not what you intend....`file=file.choose()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of the **signature** of the function that you are calling:

```
dat <- read.csv(file=result of file.choose(),header=T)
```

involves calling a function, `read.csv()` and assigning the return value to the variable `dat`. So, the error is pointing to what you are passing to the `read` function. The signature of that function is the parameters that it expects to execute properly.

You are sending two parameters, `file` and `header`. `header` is getting a `boolean` value of `T`. But you are sending `file` some text that won't even parse as a string because they aren't quoted. So the compiler will be **very** confused about what is supposed to be passed as the value for the `file` parameter. Is it `'result'`, or is it `'result of'`, etc., or is it in fact the value determined by another function, `file.choose()`.

So, in your debugging, look at the error message and then go back and look at the signature and what you are passing, and then conclude that you should be sending

```
read.csv(file=file.choose(), header=T)
```